# ¿Como actualizar los datos de un DataSet?

Tags: c#, wpf

mi problema es que no puedo actualizar los datos de mi registro, cuando modifico un dato y le doy guardar me genera el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update requiere que UpdateCommand sea válido cuando se pasa la colección DataRow con filas modificadas.'

Código de la Ventana de Modificar Datos

```
private TElectronicaDataSet electronicaDataSet;
    private TElectronicaDataSetTableAdapters.ProductosTableAdapter 
     electronicaDataSetTableAdapter;
    private CollectionViewSource viewSource;
    public Modificar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        electronicaDataSet = ((VentaElectronica.TElectronicaDataSet)(this.FindResource("tElectronicaDataSet")));
        // Cargar datos en la tabla Productos. Puede modificar este código según sea necesario.
        electronicaDataSetTableAdapter = new VentaElectronica.TElectronicaDataSetTableAdapters.ProductosTableAdapter();
        electronicaDataSetTableAdapter.Fill(electronicaDataSet.Productos);
        viewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("productosViewSource")));
        viewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            electronicaDataSetTableAdapter.Update(electronicaDataSet);
            MessageBox.Show("Guardado");



    }
```

Comment: Tienes que definir el `UpdateCommand`del `TableAdapter` para poder utilizar la función update.

Comment: Si era lo que me faltaba, gracias EGerar